# S3 file to Mysql AWS via Airflow

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-s3, airflow

I been learning how to use Apache-Airflow the last couple of months and wanted to see if anybody has any experience with transferring CSV files from S3 to a Mysql database in AWS(RDS). Or from my Local drive to MySQL.

I managed to send everything to an S3 bucket to store them in the cloud using airflow.hooks.S3_hook and it works great. I used boto3 to do this.
Now I want to push this file to a MySQL database I created in RDS, but I have no idea how to do it. Do I need to use the MySQL hook and add my credentials there and then write a python function?

Also, It doesn't have to be S3 to Mysql, I can also try from my local drive to Mysql if it's easier.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Never worked with MySQL on amazon..  But MySQL there should support [LOAD DATA LOCAL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) which can import CSV very fast assuming amazon didn't remove it from the source code and compiled without..

Comment: But keep in mind when using LOCAL option your MySQL client has to upload the file to the server first on a to slow internet connection MySQL might disconnect when uploading to big files you when the wait_timeout/interactive_timeout setting is to low..  so you might want to changed that on runtime with `SET SESSION  wait_timeout= <big_value>; SET SESSION  interactive_timeout = <big_value>; ` ... Also not sure if MySQL protocol or amazone firewall in the server/client would cap upload/download speeds of these files to save bandwidth for other clients.

Comment: Would it be better to use Postgress? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Airflow has `S3ToMySqlOperator` which can be imported via:

```
from airflow.providers.mysql.transfers.s3_to_mysql import S3ToMySqlOperator
```

Note that you will need to install MySQL provider.

For **Airflow 1.10 series** ([backport version](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-mysql/)):

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-mysql
```

For **Airflow >=2.0** ([regular version](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/) currently in Beta):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

Example usage:

```
S3ToMySqlOperator(
    s3_source_key='myfile.csv',
    mysql_table='myfile_table',
    mysql_duplicate_key_handling='IGNORE',
    mysql_extra_options="""
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            """,
    task_id= 'transfer_task',
    aws_conn_id='aws_conn',
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_conn',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Hey Elad, I am trying to use this, but when I run the DAG I get 'MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2068, 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.')'. Now the user does not seem to have the right to load a file into a table in the RDS AWS database. I can't figure out how to give a user this right. Did you also have this problem? And if yes, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

were you able to resolve the 'MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2068, 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access' issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).